# Close a popup with dynamic ID by clicking anywhere using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

Here is my html :

```
<div ng-attr-id="btnfilter{{user.name}}">
  <span class="spanbutton" style="" id="navbtn" q={{user.name}} onclick="openNav(this)">
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" style="font-size: 25px;margin-top: 23px;margin-left: -23px;"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript code to close each individual popup:

```
function openNav(x) {
  var q = $(x).attr('q');

  if ($('#mysidenav' + q).css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#mysidenav' + q).fadeIn('slow');
    $('#btnfilter' + q).html('<span class="spanbutton" id="navbtn" q=' + q + ' style="" onclick="openNav(this)"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" style="font-size: 25px;color:red;margin-top: 23px;margin-left: -23px;"></i></span>');
  } 
  else {
    $('#mysidenav' + q).fadeOut('slow');

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#mysidenav' + q).css("display", "none");
    }, 1000);

    $('#btnfilter' + q).html('<span class="spanbutton" id="navbtn" q=' + q + ' style="" onclick="openNav(this)"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" style="font-size: 25px ;margin-top: 23px;margin-left: -23px;"></i></span>');
  }
}
```

I'm using AngularJS as well. I have some dynamically generated user cards. Each of them has a button which on click opens a small popup and when I click the button for the second time, it closes the popup. I'm not able to figure out how to close the popup when I click anywhere in the body such that when any popup is closed, the html of the closed button still follows this html structure:

```
<span class="spanbutton" id="navbtn" q='+q+' style="" onclick="openNav(this)">
  <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" style="font-size: 25px ;margin-top: 23px;margin-left: -23px;"></i>
</span>
```

How do I get the `q` attribute and the `btnfilter` id etc of the parent elements so as to create the html for the closed popup as mentioned in the code above if I have to close multiple open popups by clicking anywhere?

**What I tried so far to get the id** :

```
    $(document).on('click',function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('fa-ellipsis-h')) {

  $('.spanbutton').each(function(i, obj) {
    var id = $( this ).closest("div").prop("id");
    var q = id.replace('btnfilter','');
    if ( $('#mysidenav'+q).css('display') != 'none' ) {
    $('#mysidenav'+q).fadeOut('slow');
  setTimeout( function(){
    $('#mysidenav'+q).css("display", "none");
    },1000);
    $('#btnfilter'+q).html('<span class="spanbutton" id="navbtn" q='+q+' style="" onclick="openNav(this)"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" style="font-size: 25px ;margin-top: 23px;margin-left: -23px;"></i></span>');
}
}); 
}
});
```

This code closes all the open popups perfectly when I click anywhere in the body except on the button whose class is `fa-ellipsis-h` . So this keeps the popup open until I click anywhere else in the body. This much works perfectly now.
Now the only remaining issue is if one popup is open, it doesn't get closed when I open another popup. Any suggestion on how to close other popups when a new popup is opened?

**Here is a working fiddle of the current progress
https://jsfiddle.net/81upqvb6/2/**

Comment: if you can add a working minimal example here... it'll be easier for anyone to help

Comment: Have you tried toggling a class to the body like `<body class="popup-show">` every time any of this buttons is clicked? If the body has this class, it means you need to show a popup (you can handle this in the specific clicked popup) and if the body doesn't have the class means that no popup should be shown. I think it's a cleaner approach. What are your thoughts?

Comment: check my post I have added a working fiddle of the current progress

Comment: I took a look at your fiddle and it seems to be working intermittently. May I ask, what's the intended purpose of this? Are you trying to do a toggle navigation or something like that? There might be an easier approach. If so, I think I can give you a quick example that you could use as a reference.

Comment: I'm my fiddle when the three dots are red in that case the pop-up is open. In that fiddle both the pop-up are open. I want it such that when I open any one pop-up then all the other open pop-up should get closed(the dots will turn black)

Comment: check my fiddle. I have added a mouseover event. So when you hover over grey dots it closes the open popup(red dots). But this works for a few times and then it stops working. In this workaround I have assigned a different id(navbtns) to the open popups(check the opennav function in fiddle's html). Can you help me to debug it?